# Could nesting multiple react components in this manner be considered an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I'm nesting multiple react components, but I want to make it clear how the components are nested, without requiring devs to go through the entire hierarchy of components.

So instead of doing this:

```
<Header logo=logoComponent nav=navComponent />
```

I could do this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from "./index.css";

export default React.createClass({
  // Get component by key
  getComponent(key) {
     return this.props.children.filter( (comp) => {
             return comp.key === key;
     });
  }

  render: function() {
    return (
      <header className={styles.root}>
        <div className={styles.logo}>
          {this.getComponent('logo')}
        </div>
        <div className={styles.nav}>
         {this.getComponent('navbar'}
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
});
```

Which can then be used like so:

```
export default React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Header>
        <Logo key="logo"/>
        <Navbar key="navbar"/>
      </Header>
    );
  }
});
```

Obviously this solution is a bit custom. But it does give the developer a nice immediate understanding of the way the components are nested, like with HTML.

So am I misunderstanding how to best use react if I'm using it in this way? Are there better ways to achieve the same type of nesting? Or is there something to be said for just passing multiple child components as properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have seen in cases like this when you need to render children into multiple areas is to export a few "wrapper" components from the main one — like `HeaderLogo` and `HeaderNavbar` and then use like

```
<Header>
  <HeaderLogo ... />
  <HeaderNavbar ... />
</Header>
```

I would not go with refs as these seem too fragile, but class check or whatever will be less invasive and more encapsulated from the end user — or not even "find" the right one and just render all the children.

It is ok for a component to have an informal contract that its direct children can only be these "wrapper" components.

Comment: Thanks for this, this seems like a more robust solution!